# Google Mock not reporting less than expected calls

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have written a Google Test (using Google Mock). Here is the relevant code:

```
MockObj * obj = new MockObj ();
MockDI * mock_di = new DI();
MockDIPtr mock_di_ptr(mock_di); // boost shared ptr
Data data; // sort of on array
data.append(1); data.append(2); // Add two entries
EXPECT_CALL(*obj, get_di_ptr()).WillOnce(Return(mock_di_ptr));
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_di_ptr, get_data(_,_)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(data));
EXPECT_CALL(*obj , enqueue(_)).Times(2);
```

The actual implementation is:

```
di_ptr->get_data(int, data); // data is updated via reference
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{
    enqueue(data[i]);
}
```

Basically, `enqueue()` should be called once for each entry in data. Also, the mocks are normal mocks (not Strict etc.)

This test, as expected, passes when I check for `Times(2)`.

This test, as expected, fails when I check for `Times(0)` or `Times(1)`.

BUT, This test PASSES when I check for `Times(3)`!

Why? What should I do to detect that behavior?

Comment: does it give a warning that `enqueue` is called one extra time when you expect `Times(2)`? I'm pretty sure it's you add an extra element to `data` somewhere or there is a mistake in `Data` class.

Answer (score 2):

`MockDI * mock_di = new DI();` should probably read `MockDI * mock_di = new MockDI();` to make the line `EXPECT_CALL(*mock_di_ptr, get_data(_,_)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(data));` work.

[aleguna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773602/aleguna) made a good point. The following simplified experiment yields the error `Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, mockMe(_))...`. I suggest to debug the method under test and check `data.size()` after `di_ptr->get_data()`. Then set a breakpoint in `Data::append()` and see who adds more elements.

```
#include "gtest\gtest.h"
#include "gmock\gmock.h"

using ::testing::_;

class Dependency
{
public:
    virtual ~Dependency() {}

    virtual void mockMe(int i);
};

void Dependency::mockMe(int i)
{
}


class MockDependency : public Dependency
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(mockMe, void (int i));
};


class Cut
{
public:
    void testMe(Dependency& dependency);
};

void Cut::testMe(Dependency& dependency)
{
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        dependency.mockMe(i);
    }
}


TEST(Experiment, VerifyExactCallCount)
{
    MockDependency mock = MockDependency();
    Cut cut;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, mockMe(_)).Times(3);

    cut.testMe(mock);
}
```